# cant get mysql 5.5 running on mac 10.6

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I'm new to MySQL and trying to run mysql server from terminal and cant get it running. here is what I did:
1-installed mysql.
2-opened terminal.
3-browsed to mysql directory /usr/local/mysql/bin and executed the following command ./mysqld --console.
4-then I get the following message:

```
120208  3:40:55 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Fareed-Rezaeis-iMac.lower-test  
120208  3:40:55 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Fareed-Rezaeis-iMac.lower-test  
120208  3:40:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.  
./mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)  
120208  3:40:55 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.  
120208  3:40:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled  
120208  3:40:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins  
120208  3:40:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3  
120208  3:40:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M   
120208  3:40:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool  
120208  3:40:55  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.  
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to  
InnoDB: the directory.  
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1    
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.  
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

PS: I tried browsing to the `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/bin` directory, and I'm still getting the same result. I have researched and found some suggestions like changing the basedir and datadir, but didnt get any result

Comment: One issue is "The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory" -- what are the permissions on the directory?

Comment: did you try using `sudo` to kick it off?

Comment: thanks, I  tried to use sudo and bingo!! it worked!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about user name... MySQL expecting a username to be mysql, while real username is _mysql.

You just have to fix permissions related to what I said and will work like charm.